# How to make this .htaccess rule work fine without manual adding there path `/some-dir/` or `RewriteBase /some-dir`?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path

I have http://localhost/some-dir/.htaccess `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /some-dir/$1 [R=301,L]` to remove trailing slash from URLs end.

How can I improve the same think with simple .htaccess in http://localhost/some-dir/.htaccess without manual adding there path `/some-dir/` or `RewriteBase /some-dir`? so that this rule works fine if I use it in any server path, like http://localhost/.htaccess or http://localhost/some-dir/else-path/etc/.htaccess etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use *REQUEST_URI* instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^.+/$ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you know some simple way, how can I do the same think you did with `REQUEST_URI` to more rules: `RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=4] RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2 RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2 RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N] RewriteRule (.*) /some-dir/$1 [R=301,L]` ? I know about `int:tolower`, but it requires to add it in httpd.conf and in .htaccess it does not work.

Comment: @Binyamin: You could use the [internal map function `tolower`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) or your own server side script that does the same.

Comment: @Binyamin: `RewriteMap` cannot be used in a .htaccess file (see corresponding *Context* information).

Comment: @Gumbo: I can add `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` in httpd.conf and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some-dir/${lc:$1} [R=301,L]` in .htaccess. How I remove `/some-dir/` so that it works?

Comment: @Binyamin: Try this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .+ RewriteRule ^[^A-Z]+[A-Z] ${lc:%0} [R=301,L]`.

Comment: @Gumbo: Your example works just for about each 9th URL refresh that has uppercase letters. It does not work if I use trailing slash in URL. Do you have the issue?

Comment: @Binyamin: No, it works for me. But the `[^A-Z]+` should actually be `[^A-Z]*`.

Comment: It works now fine. Thanks a lot! I'll include this things in my GitHub repository https://github.com/laukstein/ajax-seo