# How to rewrite uppercase letter URL to lowercase without `RewriteMap` or manually adding path `/some-dir/`, or `RewriteBase /some-dir`?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Unfortunately most shared servers does not support `RewriteMap`.
So I am looking for another .htaccess solution to rewrite uppercase letter URLs to lowercase without `RewriteMap` or manually adding paths `/some-dir/`, or `RewriteBase /some-dir`.

1. How do I replace path `/some-dir/` with `%{REQUEST_URI}`, so that it works in any server path, like http://localhost/.htaccess or http://localhost/some-dir/else-path/etc/.htaccess etc?
2. How do I make it working when URL contains also trailing slashes?
3. Are there even better .htaccess solutions for this problem?

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]
# Else rewrite one of each uppercase letter to lowercase
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2
# If more uppercase letters remain, re-invoke .htaccess and start over
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]
# Else do a 301 redirect to the all-lowercase URL
RewriteRule (.*) /some-dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Update:** The next .htaccess example does not require to add path name, just it has a lots of rules. Are there any way to improve it? .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
# Skip next two rules if lowercasing in progress (Remove this rule if case-conversion plug-in below is removed) 
RewriteCond %{ENV:qLow} ^yes$ [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [S=2] 
# Prevent recursion and over-writing of myURI and myQS 
RewriteCond %{ENV:qRed} ^yes$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .? - [L] 
# Get the client-requested full URI and full query string 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (/[^?]*)(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule .? - [E=myURI:%1,E=myQS:%2] 
# Uppercase to lowercase conversion plug-in (This section, along with the first noted rule above, may be removed if not needed or wanted) Skip next 28 rules if no uppercase letters in URL 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ![A-Z] 
RewriteRule .? - [S=28] 
# Else swap them out, one at a time 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1a%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1b%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1c%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1d%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1e%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1f%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1g%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1h%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1i%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1j%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1k%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1l%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1m%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1n%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1o%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1p%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1q%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1r%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1s%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1t%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1u%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1v%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1w%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1x%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1y%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1z%2] 
# Set lowercasing-in-progress flag 
RewriteRule . - [E=qLow:yes] 
# If any uppercase characters remain, re-start mod_rewrite processing from the beginning 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} [A-Z] 
RewriteRule . - [N] 
# If any characters were lowercased, set redirect required flag and reset lowercasing-in-progress flag (S=28 from above lands here) 
RewriteCond %{ENV:qLow} ^yes$ [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [E=qRed:yes,E=qLow:done] 
# End Uppercase to lowercase conversion plug-in 
RewriteCond %{ENV:qRed} ^yes$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{ENV:myURI}%{ENV:myQS} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What’s wrong with [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775142/how-to-make-this-htaccess-rule-work-fine-without-manual-adding-there-path-some/4775166#4775166)?

Comment: @Gumbo: Most of shared servers does not support `RewriteMap`.

Comment: @Gumbo: Do you have some solution for it?

Comment: @Gumbo: I update the question with an other .htaccess. Are you able to improve it?